# X11 forwarding from Amazon EC2 AMI

Tags: xorg, x11-forwarding, amazon-ec2

```
   local$> echo $DISPLAY
   :0.0
   local$> ssh -X -i PEMFILE ec2-user@AMAZONEC2_AMI
   [ec2-user@REMOTE_AMI ~]$ echo $DISPLAY

   [ec2-user@REMOTE_AMI ~]$ sudo grep X11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config ~/.ssh/*
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config:#X11Forwarding no
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config:X11Forwarding yes
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config:#X11DisplayOffset 10
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config:#X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Hence the display is not forwarded. a command like `emacs &` for instance does not show the X11 window on the local desktop.
Please advise.

Comment: Did you restart your sshd after changing `X11Forwarding` to yes?

Comment: You can also check to see if there is any interesting warning/notes when you run `ssh -vvvv -X -i ...`

Comment: X11Forwading was set to yes from before.

For -vvvv

      debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.

Could this be the reason ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I did this:

```
sudo yum install xorg-x11-xauth.x86_64 xorg-x11-server-utils.x86_64 dbus-x11.x86_64
```

and I finally got a display variable and it all started to work!

Comment: this also worked for me.

Comment: worked for me - I ran the command exactly as presented, then I logged out, and logged back in using ssh -XY user@myinstance.com

Comment: I had to *reboot my instance* in order to get sshd to start offering me X11 forwarding: simply restarting sshd wasn't enough.

Comment: Worked for me on 6.2, no restarting needed.

Answer (score 1):

Install from the above answer didn't work for my RHEL 6.2 EC2 instance. Here are steps that did work:

$ sudo yum groupinstall "X Window System"

# now disconnect and create a new SSH with -X option

Answer (score 1):

I dont have reputation so posting the answer and it worked for me on amazon RHEL

```
sudo yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```